# IE browser visual problem

Tags: internet-explorer

last question for the night!

when my website is viewed in IE, it is all screwed up compared to mozilla or chrome. I have no idea how to fix it. I think it has to do with the below divs in my site...but I'm not sure which ones.

```
#quicklinks {
width: 550px;
float: right;
background-color:#9D9AFF;
}

#buttons {
width: 200px;
padding: 62px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#zachad {
width: 310px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color:#9D9AFF;
background-image:url(jinglejarlogo3.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:auto;
float:right;
font-size: 12px;
height: 251px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 0px 30px 10px 10px;

}

#spacer {
width: 1024px;
clear:both;
}

#footerspacer {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
margin: 0px;
}

.linksinfooter li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
margin:0;
background-color:#C0C0FE;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight:bold;
border:hidden;
padding: 0.15em .15em 0.15em 1.45em;
}

#footercopyright {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
background-color:#C0C0FE;
width: 560px;
padding: 0.5em .45em .5em 1.5em;
```

Comment: You've **got** to be kidding.

Comment: You don't even say which version of IE. You should ask a more specific question than it's just all screwed up.

Comment: Code formatting, please!

Comment: sorry, IE 6 is what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of help around for this question - including other posts on here

Basically the IE Box model works differently to the Mozilla one - The simplest example is the way PADDING and MARGIN are calculated.

Mozilla adds these elements on to the defined width (eg - width: 200px, padding: 50px would create a div of 300px (200 + 50 + 50)

IE subtracts them from the inside, so the element is always the defined width (200 px) and the area inside becomes reduced by (50 + 50) px

A quick search should help

[css help with box models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89520/css-help-with-box-models)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Comment: Thank you dpmguise -that is VERY helpful. I didn't even know it was a padding/margin issue, so you pointing that out will help me investigate!